# SQL + C# ¿Variable de valor Nulo o NULL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Buen día.

Tengo una aplicación ASP.NET C# y en un WebForm debo insertar datos en una tabla. Para esto cree un procedimiento almacenado y se pueden insertar datos nulos:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Insertar_Tabla]
   @var1 INT=NULL,
   @var2 VARCHAR(10)=NULL, 
   @var3 DATETIME=NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   INSERT INTO tabla(var1,var2,var3)
   VALUES(@var1,@var2,@var3)
   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Y desde el código .cs llamo a este Procedure. Y por medio de parámetros ingreso los valores de los var.

¿Es mejor no declarar los parámetros y que el Procedure se encargue de hacerlos NULL en caso que corresponda o mejor paso las variables como un valor NULO?, ejemplo:

```
@var1 = 0; @var2=""; @var3=new DateTime();
```

Para efectos efectos prácticos y de buenas prácticas de programación, ya que el sistema actual a pesar de que es pequeño es escalable y posiblemente será modificado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El codigo deberia evaluar el valor de la variable y asignar null o no segun coresponda, algo como ser

```
public void Insertar(int? var1, string var2, DateTime? var3)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")) 
    { 

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insertar_Tabla", conn); 
        cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure; 


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var1", var1.HasValue ? var1.Value : DBNull.Value); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(var2) ? DBNull.Value : var2); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var3", var3.HasValue ? var3.Value : DBNull.Value); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```